# Python: how to merge panel data with several corresponding times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, match

I have the following data input, Dataframe 1 ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDV1c.png)). This dataframe gives the price of the company at each action date.
Dataframe 2 ([screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byXi9.png)) presents the quarter-end dates for each company. And I'd like the last column (highlighted and redded) to show the price of the most recent action. I have calculated the desired outcomes by hand, too.

I have thought about using `pd.merge(df1, df2, on['company', 'date'])`. But this doesn't produce the desired outcome.

This problem has been troubling me for a whole week. Would very much appreciate it if someone could give a hint. Thank you so much!
Regards,
Darcy

Comment: Could you please provide an MRE instead of screenshots ([How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Not fully understanding your question. You could probably do something as the below to get the max per quarter and then join. To find quarter is easy, just get month and divide by 4 and store value in a new column.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"], "col2": [1,2,3,4,5,6], "data": ["val1", "val2", "val3", "val4", "val5", "val6"]})
print(df1)
df2 = df1.groupby(["col1"])['col2'].max()
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
  col1  col2  data
0    A     1  val1
1    A     2  val2
2    A     3  val3
3    B     4  val4
4    B     5  val5
5    B     6  val6
col1
A    3
B    6
Name: col2, dtype: int64
```